# How to customize the TabbedPage's Tab-Items in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, tabbedpage

I'm using a *TabbedPage* as my MainPage of my Xamarin.Forms app (Xamarin.Forms Version: 2.3.5.239-pre3). My MainActivity inherits from *FormsAppCompatActivity*.

There are four pages of type *ContentPage* added to the TabbedPage like:

```
<TabbedPage ... >    

   <pages:FirstPage Title="Testpage1" Icon="icon.png" />
   <pages:SecondPage Title="Testpage2"  Icon="icon.png" />
   <pages:ThirdPage Title="Testpage3"  Icon="icon.png" />
   <pages:FourthPage Title="Testpage3"  Icon="icon.png" />

</TabbedPage>
```

However, the tabs are displayed like:

[image]

Now I need to change the font size of the title property, so the whole title will be displayed. Whats the best way to do this? I tried a *CustomRenderer* but I couldn't figure out how to access the tab-items.

I tried:

```
      [assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(TabbedPage), typeof(CustomTab))]
       namespace AdvancedForms.Droid.CustomRenderer
       {
            public class CustomTab : TabbedRenderer
            {
                protected override void DispatchDraw(Canvas canvas)
                {    
                  base.DispatchDraw(canvas);
                  ActionBar actionBar = activity.ActionBar;
                  // Do Stuff here
                }
            }
        }
```

But activity.ActionBar is always null.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be looking for a TabLayout, not an ActionBar. Last I checked the TabLayout is the second child in the renderer's view hierarchy so you should be able to get at it like so:

```
var tabLayout = (TabLayout)GetChildAt(1);
```

Once you have that you need to loop through the individual tabs and apply your desired font size to each tab's textview.

Helpful hint, the view hierarchy looks like this:

```
MsiTabbedRenderer
    FormsViewPager
    TabLayout
        SlidingTabStrip
            TabView
                AppCompatImageView
                AppCompatTextView
            TabView
                AppCompatImageView
                AppCompatTextView
            TabView
                AppCompatImageView
                AppCompatTextView
            ...
```

The method I use to generate this information is included below for your enjoyment:

```
    public static void DebugLayout(this View self, int indent = 0)
    {
        // write info about me first
        var indents = new string('\t', indent);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(indents + self.GetType().Name);

        // check if I'm a view group
        var vg = self as ViewGroup;
        if (vg == null) return;

        // enumerate my children
        var children = Enumerable.Range(0, vg.ChildCount).Select(x => vg.GetChildAt(x));

        // recurse on each child
        foreach (var child in children)
            DebugLayout(child, indent+1);
    }
```

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late answer! Your suggestion worked very well for me, thank you! :)

Where did you get that hierarchy view from? Are there some good tools where i can see such views?

Comment: I added the extension method I use to generate my view layout "cheat sheet"

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate that! :)

Answer (score 0):

For Custom tab view/page i am using the xam.Tabview (Xamarin.Forms) Component and it's working as expected.
It has the support for custom header and content view.

Install Nuget: [TabView Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xam.TabView)

Sample: [Tabview Sample](https://github.com/rajeshangappan/Xamarin/tree/master/Samples/TabViewSample)