# Menu Item not showing in Xamarin.Forms after navigation back

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, searchview

I'm developing a **Xamarin.Forms Android-App** where on a ContentPage a *CustomRenderer* is being used to display a SearchView in the Header of the Page. The CustomRenderer for the "SearchPage" class looks like the following:

```
 /// <summary>
///     The search page renderer.
/// </summary>
public class SearchPageRenderer : PageRenderer
{
    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets or sets the search view.
    /// </summary>
    private SearchView searchView;

    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets or sets the toolbar.
    /// </summary>
    private Toolbar toolbar;

    /// <summary>
    ///     Reaction on the disposing of the page.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">A value indicating whether disposing.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (this.searchView != null)
        {
            this.searchView.QueryTextChange -= this.OnQueryTextChangeSearchView;
        }

        this.toolbar?.Menu?.RemoveItem(Resource.Menu.mainmenu);
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Reaction on the element changed event.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e">The event argument.</param>
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Page> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e?.NewElement == null || e.OldElement != null)
        {
            return;
        }

        this.AddSearchToToolBar();
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Adds a search item to the toolbar.
    /// </summary>
    private void AddSearchToToolBar()
    {
        this.toolbar = (CrossCurrentActivity.Current?.Activity as MainActivity)?.FindViewById<Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);

        if (this.toolbar != null)
        {
            this.toolbar.Title = this.Element.Title;
            this.toolbar.InflateMenu(Resource.Menu.mainmenu);

            this.searchView = this.toolbar.Menu?.FindItem(Resource.Id.action_search)?.ActionView?.JavaCast<SearchView>();

            if (this.searchView != null)
            {
                this.searchView.QueryTextChange += this.OnQueryTextChangeSearchView;
                this.searchView.ImeOptions = (int)ImeAction.Search;
                this.searchView.MaxWidth = int.MaxValue;
                this.searchView.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.textfield_search_holo_light);
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Reaction on the text change event of the searchbar.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The event sender.</param>
    /// <param name="e">The event argument.</param>
    private void OnQueryTextChangeSearchView(object sender, SearchView.QueryTextChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        var searchPage = this.Element as SearchPage;
        searchPage?.SearchCommand?.Execute(e?.NewText);
    }
}
```

Thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44197406/how-to-customize-the-tabbedpages-tab-items-in-xamarin-forms) Stack-Overflow Thread, i got it working like a charm so far.
Now, if the user taps on a item in the "SearchPage", a new ContentPage (called "DetailPage") is pushed to the NavigationStack using the following method:

```
private async Task PushPageAsync(object model, ContentPage page, INavigation navigation)
    {
        page.BindingContext = model;
        await navigation.PushAsync(page).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
```

That works without problems. But if the users navigates from the "DetailPage" back to the "SearchPage" by using the Back-Button, **the customized Search-Header isn't showing at all**.

What I tried:

Using the "OnAppearing" event of the page instead of the "OnElementChanged". That didn't solve the problem at first sight. However, if I add a Task.Delay(500) to the OnAppearing-Method and then add the SearchView **again**, it is displayed. But this fix seems quite ugly, and if i sleep the app and resume while using the SearchPage, the Search-Widget is showing **twice**.

So my question is:

**Is there a bug in Xamarin or am I doing something wrong?**

Comment: Try overridinge `OnRestart`. I recently found an instance where binding my lists needed to be re-done when the view was brought back to the front and this is the method which was called consistently

Comment: What solution did you finally opt for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a bug in Xamarin or am I doing something wrong?

I can't say it's a bug, I prefer to consider it is as by design. The real problem is that you're trying to modify the `Toolbar` in your custom renderer, and based on your description, you're using `NavigationPage`, its [NavigationPageRenderer](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android/AppCompat/NavigationPageRenderer.cs) will update the view of `Toolbar` each time when current page is changed.

So you're doing right to use the "OnAppearing" event of the page instead of the "OnElementChanged", which cause another problem, the updating of `Toolbar` is be delayed when the old page is removed as you can see from the source code in `RemovePage` method, while the `OnAppearing` method will be executed immediately when the new page is shown:

```
Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10), () =>
{
    UpdateToolbar();
    return false;
});
```

So I don't think you're doing anything wrong too, the method you used `await Task.Delay(500);` can quickly solve this issue.

Based on your description here:

> But this fix seems quite ugly, and if i sleep the app and resume while using the SearchPage, the Search-Widget is showing twice.

I suggest to change your `SearchPage` to a `View`, and then dynamically add/remove this view from pages:

```
public class SearchPage : View
{
  ...
}
```

and renderer for it (other codes are the same, only change to inherit from `ViewRenderer` and the parameter of `OnElementChanged` is different):

```
public class SearchPageRenderer : ViewRenderer
{
    private SearchView searchView;

    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets or sets the toolbar.
    /// </summary>
    private Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar toolbar;

    ...

    /// <summary>
    ///     Reaction on the element changed event.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e">The event argument.</param>

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.View> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        if (e?.NewElement == null || e.OldElement != null)
        {
            return;
        }
        this.AddSearchToToolBar();
    }

   ...

}
```

Then you can use it as a control/view in pages where you want to show it, not directly as a `Page`. For example, I want to show this search view in my `MainPage`, then navigate to `MainPage` in App.xaml.cs:

```
MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
```

`MainPage`'s layout:

```
<StackLayout>
   ...
</StackLayout>
```

At last override the `OnAppearing` and `OnDisappearing` method of the `MainPage`:

```
protected override async void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();
    await Task.Delay(500);
    var content = this.Content as StackLayout;
    content.Children.Add(new SearchPage());
}

protected override void OnDisappearing()
{
    base.OnDisappearing();
    var content = this.Content as StackLayout;
    foreach (var child in content.Children)
    {
        var searchpage = child as SearchPage;
        if (searchpage != null)
        {
            content.Children.Remove(searchpage);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

By the way, if you want to navigate from `MainPage` here to other pages, you can code like this:

```
this.Navigation.PushAsync(new Page1());
```

There is no need to create a `PushPageAsync` task for it.

Comment: Forgot to say, the reason I suggested to use `ViewRenderer` instead of `PageRenderer` is that I don't know how you add `SearchPage` again, you can also directly try to remove it in `OnDisappearing`.

Comment: Thank you very much for this great answer!
Seems like this task delay is necessary. I like your idea of using a view instead of a page for custom rendering, so I'm going to try this out. :)

Comment: What is the point of adding     await Task.Delay(500); in OnAppearing method?

Comment: @user3713398, As I've said in the answer, in the source code of `NavigationPageRenderer`, in the `RemovePage` method, it is hard coded there to delay a little.

Comment: @GraceFeng : your logic works like charm. thank you. can you Please send ViewRenderer for IOS as well.

Comment: @KrunalBagadia, sorry, I'm not familiar with ios, I suggest to open a new thread and ask your question, thank you.